# How can I resolve the DataSourceException error when trying to view Tableau Administrative Views

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to see the "Traffic to Views" administrative view on a Tableau Server version 9.1. I am an administrator. When I am on the Server Status page and then click the "Traffic to Views" link I receive an error saying "DataSourceException: The drivers necessary to connect to the database server 'localhost' are not properly installed on Tableau Server." How can I resolve the DataSourceException error when trying to view Tableau Administrative Views?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the error was raised because PostgreSQL drivers were not installed. Our anti-virus software raised an alert saying that the drivers contained a trojan virus and prevented the installation. The solution was to create an exception with the anti-virus software to allow the driver installation.